# Storing JavaScript object into SQL server

Tags: javascript, sql-server, serialization

I'm currently working on a school project that requires a scheduling calendar as it's core function. However, I downloaded a third party java script calendar from the net and edit the java script codes accordingly to my project requirements.

But as a noob in asp.net, I do not know how to save the javascript object into my SQL server. Is there a guide or a website where I can learn how to do it ? Below is a set of my java script, so how do I use JSON with this code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------c ------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event2').each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });






    });







    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------c ------------------*/

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });






    });


    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            // calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },




        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


            var title = prompt('Rename Event Title:');

            calEvent.title = title;
            // copiedEventObject.title = title;
            alert('Altered Event : ' + calEvent.title);


            // change the border color just for fun
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

        },







        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');


            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            //    copiedEventObject.title = 'abc';     //<<<Change the title



            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your object JSON a String with `JSON.stringify(object)`, and save it in the database, then when you access the data and recover this String, you send the client and to parse a JSON object with `JSON.parse (string)`

Comment: but how do i convert this object with json?

Comment: exactly what data you need to store in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `JSON.stringify()` and store it in the DB. Also make sure you compress the data which will save you lot of space.

```js
let data = { 'applicationId': '123456', 'digest': JSON.stringify(digest) };
const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
ps.input('applicationId', sql.VarChar);
ps.input('digest', sql.NVarChar); // When storing the actual data we compress it and store it. 

await ps.prepare(`INSERT INTO ${DIGEST_TABLE} VALUES (@applicationId, COMPRESS(@digest))`);
await ps.execute(data)
```

Then when you are reading you can decompress it and read the data.

```js
SELECT CAST(DECOMPRESS(digest) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS digest FROM SOME_TABLE
```